# What is the purpose of the fourth line in this code

Tags: javascript, html, performance

Removing  `value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;` dosen't make any change to the output. What is the purpose of this line.

```
function incrementValue()
    {
        var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
        value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
        value++;
        document.getElementById('number').value = value;
    }
```

Comment: to separate line 3 and 5 ... and also to make sure `value` is a `Number` - do you know what [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) is?

Comment: the line should also test for empty string: `value = value=="" || isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;`

Comment: @JaromandaX: `value` will never be `null` with the code above.

Comment: @mplungjan: `value` from `input` elements was never `null`, not even in IE5.5.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I am from WAY before IE5.5 ;) My first JS was in NN 2.0 beta 3 and IE3.2

Comment: @mplungjan: Heh, same as mine. But I can't recall having checked that specific thing. In any case, no need to confuse people with *truly* ancient history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checks if the parameter `value` is Not-a-Number(NaN).

- If it's indeed a NaN it sets its value to 0.
- Otherwise it sets its original value by returning the same `value` parameter.

The format

```
<condition>?<truth scenario>:<false scenario>
```

you see here is a shorthand for:

```
 if (<condition>) {
      <truth scenario>
   } else {
      <false scenario>
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a filter for getting only numerical values into an input element and increment the value.

Basically the check returns zero if a `NaN` is returned from parseInt.

You could use a logical OR to prevent falsy values and use a zero instead.

```js
function incrementValue() {
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10) || 0;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('number').value = value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="number" onchange="incrementValue()">
```

Answer (score 0):

`NaN` stands for `Not a Number`, which represents an invalid numeric value. If you type an invalid number in your `number` field (for example, you type `four` instead of `4`), when parsing it with `parseInt`, it will return a `NaN` value.

The fourth line of your code `value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;` will transform that `NaN` value into a `0`, so arithmetic operations may be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

See the `console.log` .its showing what happens inside  .If you type the alphabetic value.[`isNaN()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjLmM_xwvHTAhXLRo8KHTo1ARoQFggqMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FisNaN&usg=AFQjCNGLrE-F7Ps96vTxYu1dJpStV_B9Kw) validate its the value is `NaN` return the value as `0` If is not NaN return the value of input

```js
function incrementValue()
    {
        var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
        console.log(value)
        value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
        value++;
        document.getElementById('number').value = value;
    }
```

```html
<input id="number" value="sx">
<button onclick="incrementValue()"">valid</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

**NaN means:**
not a number.

If you try to calculate with this value (NaN) you will get JavaScript fatal errors so this check is to prevent this.

By the way, this script will not work properly because you will overwrite the "value" every time you call this function.